# Nuxt 3 print to terminal : [Vue Router warn]: No match found for location with path "/json/version"

Tags: nuxt3

I created new nuxt3 app follow https://nuxt.com/docs/getting-started/installation.
When I ran: nuxt dev --port 4000 : I didn't see warning log
But When I ran:

- nuxt build
- PORT=80 HOST=0.0.0.0 node .output/server/index.mjs
  => It prints to terminal every second. See below image

[Warning log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kfqdu.png)

How can to turn of it

Comment: Strange! If you're mentioning that this warning appeared immediately after creating a new Nuxt3 project, it might be worth recreating another project on your machine and testing it again.